# Help on the grammar with this usage of "zu"

Tags: preposition, german-to-english, dative

Here is the example sentence:

> Nach einer betrieblichen Störung in Hegermühle kommt es leider zu Verspätungen und eventuellen Ausfällen.

It was an announcement taken from S-Bahn Berlin's website.

I was wondering if *zu* is used as a preposition here? And if so, what case (Dativ?) is this phrase *zu Verspätungen und eventuellen Ausfällen* in?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, *zu* is a perfectly ordinary preposition here.

*Zu* is just one of many short function words serving grammatical purposes that can also serve as common content words; the article *der* is also a relative pronoun or a demonstrative pronoun, the verb affix *an-* also serves as a normal preposition, etc.

The example sentence might be slightly hard to read because the particle *zu* is used with infinitives, which tend to end in *-en*, while here the preposition *zu* governs dative plural forms, which *also* end with *-en*. As you see, inflection endings also tend to get reused. Nevertheless, context usually makes it clear enough what kind of *zu* you're dealing with.